# Library for convex and decreasing regression in cpp (preferrably based on spline)

Tags: c++, r, regression-analysis

I need a method to fit a convex and decreasing curve on a set of points (the points may not be monotonic) in cpp.

I found a existing method which is based on quadratic splines being fit over points with constraints set as decreasing and convex (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cobs/versions/1.3-5/topics/cobs). However, I need some implementation in cpp.

I have explored literature in cpp too.
ALGLIB: [https://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php#:~:text=ALGLIB%20package%20supports%20curve%20fitting,best%20one%20dimensional%20fitting%20algorithms](https://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php#:%7E:text=ALGLIB%20package%20supports%20curve%20fitting,best%20one%20dimensional%20fitting%20algorithms).
offers monotonic splines but they are monotonic only if the given data was monotonic

https://github.com/decile-team/jensen
Offers only convex optimization but not monotonic

Can someone recommend me a method which can be easily implemented or available in cpp library?